# What is the best way to edit out foreground objects?

Tags: photo-editing

What is the best method in photoshop to remove the white line in this image? I've tried the spot heal brush and it didn't do that well of a job.

[image]

Comment: Did you try *content-aware delete*?

Comment: Is it called content aware fill? Can't really find content aware delete.

Comment: It's listed in the fill dialog as `Content-Aware`.

Comment: In Photoshop CS5.5, if press *Delete* a dialog appears with a drop-down box. One of the options there is *Content-Aware*. It may be different depending on your version. Sounds similar though.

Comment: It's not a duplicate though. None of the tips there for humans work for this line. I've tried content aware patch, same thing. Can anyone give it a shot?

Comment: What version of Photoshop?

Comment: @MikeW - content-aware patch is new in CS6, so it must be either CS6 or CC.

Comment: First of all, just because the _answers_ on the other question are not suiting you, does not mean the _questions_ are not a duplicate. You are trying to tell me that none of these tools work? Clone Stamp Tool, Duplicate layer techniques, Healing Brush, Patch Tool, Spot Healing Brush, Content Aware Fill, Content Aware Patch? I am doubtful that is the case.

Comment: A solid contrasting line across the entire image is a different scenario to removing some small blobs from the background, and different tools may work.  e.g. for his one the spot healing brush may mostly remove it in one swipe, where cloning and patch tool aren't as good for this image.  But the toolset is the same, and really for each image you have to try them all to see what works best, so in that regard the answers aren't definitive.

Answer (score 1):

The tool I would try first is the spot healing brush tool (I believe CS5 and later).  It's at the top of the list of healing tools if you press the shortcut key "J".  Click on one end of the white line, then holding shift click on the other end.  The Shift+click will draw a straight line across.  The line isn't exactly straight so you may have to use a slightly wider brush.  This may not give perfect results, but should do a good job and you can then clean up with clone stamp or other tools.  If you do it in a duplicate layer you can mask out any areas that you don't like and try a second swipe.

After that, duplicate the image and add a black mask to hide it.  Use the move tool to move the duplicate layer up and over a few pixels (the width of the line or a bit more).  Then using a white brush paint over the white line to let the duplicate layer to show through revealing pixels from the green background and zebra.